# Do we have to restart git after updating .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

We just updated our `.gitignore`. If we want `git status` to reflect the updates, do we need to first restart git?

Comment: You cannot "restart" git. It doesn't work that way. It's a program that starts, does what it needs to and terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git itself is “restarted” every time you invoke it, so no: you don't need to “restart” it.

If you are referring to a Git GUI (that is, you aren't actually typing `git status` into a console), it depends on which GUI you are using. `git-gui` and `gitk` don't need restarting, but others may.